# Definition of hoistfree

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I have some questions concerning the function hoistfree from the Haskell library [Control.Monad.Free](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/src/Control-Monad-Free.html#hoistfree). Given a transformation `f` between two functors, hoistfree f produces a morphism between the corresponding free monads. Here is its definition.

```
hoistFree :: Functor g => (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Free f b -> Free g b
hoistFree _ (Pure a)  = Pure a
hoistFree f (Free as) = Free (hoistFree f <$> f as)
```

**Question 1** How does Haskell know that `<$>` is the map associated to `g` and not to `f`, `Free f` or `Free g`?

**Question 2** Why hoistfree has not been defined as

```
hoistFree :: Functor g => (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Free f b -> Free g b
hoistFree _ (Pure a)  = Pure a
hoistFree f (Free as) = Free (f (hoistFree f <$> as))
```

?

If `f` is a natural transformation, these two definitions coincide. The second definition however always satisfies the relation

```
hoistfree f = iter (wrap . f) . map return
```

which looks pretty natural. Furthermore, there are a few basic functions that can be expressed using `iter_map f g = iter f . map g`. For example,

```
(=<<) f = iter_map wrap f
```

**Question 3** Is iter_map defined somewhere? It looks like a monadic mapreduce. I didn't see it in the base library. Is there some gain in fusioning iter and map? In a few other languages, this is the case, but I am not sure for Haskell.

Comment: The Functor constrain on your definition of `hoistFree` is wrong, isn't it? The inferred type is `Functor f =>   (f (Free g a) -> g (Free g a)) -> Free f a -> Free g a`.

Comment: @michael I don't know why the wider type is not inferred. This is a mystery to me.

Comment: The type inferencer doesn't infer rank 2 types, or is that what you mean?  This is the 'wider type' in the sense that it applies to more cases.

Comment: @michael Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: In this case wouldn't it just be wrong to infer the rank 2 argument? It's intuitively an arbitrary restriction on the first argument, if we consider the definition as a random bit of Haskell.  In more interesting cases the type checker won't be able to see that the definition is good without the explicit rank 2 signature.

Answer (score 5):

**Question 1**

Because of type inference, which chooses `<$>` from `g`. Indeed, in

```
Free (hoistFree f <$> f as)
```

`f as` has type `g <something>`, hence the `<$>` is the one given by `Functor g`.

**Question 2**

I think that, in Haskell, `f` is always a natural transformation. Any polymorphic function `f a -> g a` must be natural in `a`, by parametricity / free theorem.
Both definitions being equivalent, I'm not sure if any one is the "best". Maybe yours is. Or maybe the original one has better performance in practice. It looks a bit as the `foldr` vs `foldl'` argument on associative operators, where there's no clear winner.

**Question 3** No idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But even if f is always a natural transformation mathematically speaking, there may be several non-equivalent ways to implement it, e.g. [this post](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/02/how-many-functions-are-there-from-to.html).

Comment: @stackman True. Maybe someone else can provide more insight. Understanding the precise strictness level of a higher-level function is quite challenging.